# Warning message when attempting to destroy a foreign used record laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I have a foreign relationship with Worker and Area.

Obviously when you want to delete an Area and it's already assigned, Laravel will throw an error.

I wanted to add a warning to show the user that he can't do that so I managed to do this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $area = Area::findOrFail($id);
    $workers = Worker::all();

    foreach ($workers as $worker)
    {
        if ($worker->area_id == $id)
        {
            $match = 'found';
        }
    }

    if ($match == 'found')
    {
        \Session::flash('alert-danger', 'No puedes eliminar area relacionada con empleado, elimina primero el empleado!');

        return redirect()->route('areas.index');
    } else
    {
        $area->delete();
        \Session::flash('alert-success', 'Area eliminada correctamente!');

        return redirect()->route('areas.index');
    }
}
```

To explain the code above, first I loop thru all the workers and compare the `workers.area_id` with the `areas.id`, if a match is found it will be stored in the `$match` variable.

Then if a match has been "found" I use Laravel's flash to send the user a message telling him that he cannot delete this area because it's related to a worker, then redirect to index. Otherwise destroy the area and redirect.

That works and it's okey, I just wanted to know if Laravel has some class already implemented to manage this kind of situations. Yesterday you guys helped me with eloquent and now I have about 100 less lines of code :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution one: let it cascade the delete, so if you delete the parent, the children get deleted too:

```
$table->foreign('worker_id')->references('id')->on('workers')->onDelete('cascade');
```

If you don't want to do that, you could just catch the exception, instead of looping through first:

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $area = Area::findOrFail($id);
    try {
        $area->delete();
        \Session::flash('alert-success', 'Area eliminada correctamente!');
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        \Session::flash('alert-danger', 'No puedes eliminar area relacionada con empleado, elimina primero el empleado!');
    }
    return redirect()->route('areas.index');
}
```

That might be the wrong exception to catch, but I think that is the one it throws.  And my cascade syntax might be wrong, haven't used Laravel in a while.  But this is the general idea of the two ways I would do it

Answer (score 1):

I think the second solution by dave is better, but I would add something for check the error is for integrity constraint violation:

```
catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
if($e->getCode() == "23000"){
    \Session::flash('alert-danger', 'No puedes eliminar area relacionada con empleado, elimina primero el empleado!');
}}
```

The code 23000 is sql code for integrity constraint violation, so in this way we only avoid integrity constraint violation.